# Rename columns in a pandas.DataFrame via lookup from a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with columns like:

```py
>>> df.columns
['A_ugly_column_name', 'B_ugly_column_name', ...]
```

and a Series, `series_column_names`, with nice column names like:

```py
>>> series_column_names = pd.Series(
    data=["A_ugly_column_name", "B_ugly_column_name"],
    index=["A", "B"],
)
>>> print(series_column_names)
A         A_ugly_column_name
B         B_ugly_column_name
...
Name: column_names, dtype: object
```

Is there a nice way to rename the columns in `df` according to `series_column_names`? More specifically, I'd like to rename the columns in `df` to the index in `column_names` where value in the series is the old column name in `df`.

Some context - I have several DataFrames with columns for the same thing, but they're all named slightly differently. I have a DataFrame where, like here, the index is a standardized name and the columns contain the column names used by the various DataFrames. I want to use this "name mapping" DataFrame to rename the columns in the several DataFrames to the same thing.

###### a solution i have...

So far, the best solution I have is:

```
>>> df.rename(columns=lambda old: series_column_names.index[series_column_names == old][0])
```

which works but I'm wondering if there's a better, more pandas-native way to do this.

Comment: your series is split by whitespace ?

Comment: @Umar.H the whitespace separates index and values

Comment: can you add the create statement for your series please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first create a dictionary out of your series by using `.str.split`

```
cols = {y : x for x,y in series_column_names.str.split('\s+').tolist()}

print(cols)
```

---

#### Edit.

If your series has your target column names as the index and the values as the series you can still create a dictionary by inversing the keys and values.

```
cols = {y : x for x,y in series_column_names.to_dict().items()}
```

or

```
cols = dict(zip(series_column_names.tolist(), series_column_names.index))
```

---

```
print(cols)
{'B_ugly_column_name': 'B_nice_column_name',
 'C_ugly_column_name': 'C_nice_column_name',
 'A_ugly_column_name': 'A_nice_column_name'}
```

---

then assign your column names.

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(cols)

print(df)

   A_nice_column_name  B_nice_column_name
0                   0                   0
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. this works but i'm wondering if there's a better way than to_dict and reversing?

Comment: if this is indeed the best way, i'll accept this answer. thank you again (upvoting).

Comment: @grisaitis best is subjective, to me readable code that you can come back to is best, since you're using a small series speed isn't really an issue here. Anyway see edit for another way to create a dictionary from two iterables.

Comment: the `dict(zip(series_column_names, series_column_names.index))` is nice. thanks again!

Comment: Is mapping possible within pd.read_csv?

Comment: @Gobrel - I don't think so - what are you trying to do? might be better to open a new question

Comment: @Umar.H Currently I read a csv and after reading it I map column names on that dataframe. Thought maybe there is something already in pd.read_csv.

Comment: @Gobrel I think it's possible - open a new question and tag me I'll take a look remember to read [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Just inverse the index/values in `series_column_names` and use it to rename. It doesn't matter if there are extra names.

```
series_column_names = pd.Series(
    data=["A_ugly", "B_ugly", "C_ugly"],
    index=["A", "B", "C"],
)
df.rename(columns=pd.Series(series_column_names.index.values, index=series_column_names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be as simple as this?

```
series_column_names = pd.Series(['A_nice_column_name', 'B_nice_column_name'])

df.columns = series_column_names
```

Comment: Unfortunately not because it's not necessarily ordered

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though! I edited the example in my question to better define the situation.